# Convert audio file to a byte array in matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, audio, wav

I want to convert an audio file (.wav/.mp3) to a byte array like in C#.  Here's my code,

```
string imageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".mp3";
byte[] file = System.Convert.FromBase64String(Filep);
File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("FILE/" + imageName), file);
return imageName;
```

Comment: actually this is working. I want to do the same process in matlab

Comment: Do you want the raw audio data, or do you simply want to open up the file and access the data?

Comment: I want the raw data(save the audio to a matrix)

Comment: Please edit your post.  What you are asking for in the comments to me in comparison to what you're after in your original post are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the raw audio data, use [`audioread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html).  You call it like so:

```
[y,Fs] = audioread(filename);
```

`filename` would be the file name of your file (.mp3/.wav) and what is returned is a matrix of values stored in `y` and the sampling frequency of the file in `Fs`.  `y` would be a matrix such that the number of rows tells you the number of samples that your audio consists of, and the number of columns tells you how many channels the audio has.  For example, mono audio would be a single column vector while stereo audio would be a two-column matrix: the first column being the left channel and the second column being the right channel.

For more information, check out the MathWorks doc I linked you to above.

Comment: i want to get some special characteristics of an audio file(like frequencies or amplitudes)to further analysis.sampling rate and sampling frequency is not what I am looking for. I want to match two audio clips. first one is the original audio clip and the second one is a snippet of that audio clip.

Comment: @dinoos - What you are asking for here in comparison to what your original post is asking for are **not** the same.  What you basically are looking for has already been done by [Shazam](http://www.shazam.com) and [SoundHound](http://www.soundhound.com/).  They match audio clips together by looking at the frequency decomposition of the two signals.  FWIW, the Shazam algorithm is already public and its MATLAB code available here: http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/matlab/fingerprint/ - BTW, what you're asking for is too broad.  You won't get any answers from any of us.  Sorry.  Good luck!